# since in python we cannot pass by reference then how to change the value of variable present in other scope in python

Tags: python, scope, global, keyword

I used two techniques just to tackle this problem but was unable to resolve it. I want to modify the value of 'a' from 5 to 6 here but it is not modifying.

```py
def f2():
    a=5
    def insidefun(c):
        if c==0:
            return
        if c==1:
            global a
            a=6
        return insidefun(c-1)
    insidefun(3)
    print(a)# result is 5 but I want to modify it to 6.global keyword is no working here
f2()
```

Another way I tried to do it by passing the value in function.

```py
def f2():
    a=5
    def insidefun(c,a):
        if c==0:
            return
        if c==1:
            a=6
        return insidefun(c-1,a)
    insidefun(3,a)
    print(a) #still it is printing 5.
f2()
```

is there any way I can change the value of 'a' inside my function .

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is `nonlocal a`. This basically says: assume that `a` is coming from a higher level scope.

Comment: @flakes Please try to look for duplicates when the solution is that simple.

Answer (score 0):

using 'nonlocal a' I got the desired output.

```
def f2():
    a=5
    def insidefun(c):
        if c==0:
            return
        if c==1:
            nonlocal a
            a=6
        return insidefun(c-1)
    insidefun(3)
    print(a)
f2()
```